# How to search for a particular word from a non iterable json object

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on resume parser. Now I am trying to add dynamism to code. So lets consider there are two resumes in a folder, I'm parsing them and returning required information as below in a json format in my API.

```
[
  {
    "dob": [], 
    "education": [
      [
        "MCA", 
        "2009"
      ]
    ], 
    "email": "Id:abcd@gmail.com", 
    "mobile_number": "+911234567", 
    "name": "abcd", 
    "personal_website": [
      "abcd@gmail.com", 
      "http://www.arthavidhya.com", 
      "http://www.myhealthwatcher.com", 
      "http://www.i-southernworld.com/", 
      "http://www.i-chiletravel.com/"
    ], 
    "skills": [
      "Bootstrap", 
      "Javascript", 
      "Js", 
      "Jquery", 
      "Interactive", 
      "My-sql", 
      "Css", 
      "Ajax", 
      "Apache", 
      "Php", 
      "Codignator"
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "dob": [], 
    "education": [
      [
        "Btech", 
        "2018"
      ]
    ], 
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",  
    "mobile_number": "+91987654321", 
    "name": "xyz", 
    "personal_website": [
      "xyz@gmail.com", 
      "https://github.com/xyz"
    ], 
    "skills": [
      "Sqlite", 
      "Tensorflow", 
      "C++", 
      "C", 
      "Php", 
      "Android", 
      "Mysql", 
      "Flask", 
      "Nlp", 
      "Javascript", 
      "Css", 
      "Keras", 
      "Machine learning", 
      "Python"
    ]
  }
```

Now lets say I am passing input as 'Keras' then only the second file should be displayed. What logic can be used here? The difficulty I'm facing here is that my output is not iterable. Can someone give me hint on how to tackle this?

Please comment if my question is not clear or require any more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
def function1(json_object, name):
    match = []
    for dict in json_object:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            if (isinstance(value, str) and value == name) or (isinstance(value, list) and name in value):
                match.append(dict)
    return match


def main():
    print(json.dumps(function1(DATA, "Keras"), indent=2))
```

Basically we are checking if the value in `dict` is a `string` or `list` and trying to match with the string or list items.

Up to you to make it case insensitive or whatever change you want

Answer (score 0):

Your output is very much iterable because it is a list. 
What you can do is, loop through each resume, check if the required skills exists in the skill part of the resume, if it does, add it to the list of resumes that have the same skill. Finally, return the list in json. I hope the code snippet below will make it more clear!

```
import json
#resumes is the json data you have, skill is a string of the skill you're looking for.
def match_skill(resumes, skill):
  resumes_with_skill = []
  for resume in resumes:
    if skill in resume['skills']:
      resumes_with_skill.append(resume)
  return json.dumps(resumes_with_skill)

match_skill(data, 'Keras')
```